# Publish an event using Struts 2 jQuery Plugin

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I want to use the `publish`/`subscribe` framework which is used internally by Strust2 jQuery plugin.

The user can select an account number from a list or type it in a textbox.

I want to publish an event when text box or select option changes. So the user can only type textbox OR select something from select box:

```
<s:textfield name="account"  onblur="$.publish('accountChanged',this,event)"/>
<s:select name="accountList" list="destinationAccounts"
    onblur="$.publish('accountChanged',this,event)"/>
```

**Below is the js:**

```js
$.subscribe('accountChanged', function(event, data) {
    alert("New data is: " + data.value);
    if ( event.target.id=='account') {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

**Here are issues:**

1. The data.value only works for textbox, for select box the `data.value` is undefined.
2. I want to know which target received the event. `event.target.id` is not working! I think the event object is not a jQuery event object?

I reviewed the sample showcase application, but could not find any.

Am I calling `$.publish` method correctly? Are there better ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you subscribe to topics keep the topic name unique for each tag that allows to separate handlers for the tag. The new event is created each time you publish the topic in the `onblur` event. The `textfield` handler for topic works as you described. The `select` tag doesn't work because wrong parameter passed as the `data`. The example of the working code

```
<s:textfield name="account"  onblur="$(this).publish('accountChanged', this, event)"/>
<s:select name="accountList" list="{'list1', 'list2','list3'}" onblur="$(this).publish('accountListChanged', this, event)"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.subscribe('accountChanged', function(event, data) {
    alert("accountChanged: " + data.value);
  });
  $.subscribe('accountListChanged', function(event, data) {
    alert("accountListChanged: " + data.parentElement.value);
  });
</script>
```

As you can see the `data.value` is undefined because `data.parentElement.value` should be used. `event.target.id` is not working because `event.originalEvent.target.id` should be used. The `event` object is a jQuery event, but `originalEvent` is DHTML object which is `blur`.

I don't know about your requirements, if you need to subscribe/publish events or use the original event handlers, I can't say what is better in this situation.

Comment: The requirement is simple.

There is a hidden text field in the page. The value of this hidden text should be set as follow:
If user types a value in the textfield then the hidden field value should be set with text field value. 
If user selects account from the select input then the hidden field value should be set from the selected option.
I assumed that the I must publish 'accountChanged' topic when textbox changes and when user selects some thing from select list. This is way I published same topic name. Then in the subscribe method I wanted to set the hidden value by reading data.value

Comment: Ok, do you know how to do it?

Comment: Yes! Your answer guided me alot. I will put the answer for others

Answer (score 0):

The below code solved my issue:

As I could not find any example of publish/subscribe framework, I hope below example will help others!

The jsp will be

*You must call `${this).publish` not `$.publish`*

```
<s:textfield name="account"  onblur="$(this).publish('destinationChanged', this, event)"/>
<s:select name="accountList" list="{'list1', 'list2','list3'}" onblur="$(this).publish('destinationChanged', this, event)" emptyOption="true"/>
<s:textfield name="destinationAccount" type="hidden" />
```

And the JS will be

```
$.subscribe('destinationChanged', function(event, data) {
            //If user types in the textbox 
            //then get the value and make the select box shows an empty option 
        if( !!data.value){
            destinationAccount= data.value;
        $('#destinationKnownAccount').val($("#destinationKnownAccount option:first").val());
        } else{
             //The user selected an account from select box. 
             // So get the value from select box and clean textbox          
            destinationAccount= data.parentElement.value;
            $('#destinationUnknownAccount').val('');
        }
            //Set the hidden box        
        $('#destinationAccount').val( destinationAccount);


    });
```

As mentioned one can use `event.originalEvent.target.id` to find which target was selected.